# How to get the right arithmetic value?

Tags: math, binary, integer-arithmetic

Is it possible through some sort of arithmetic or logic operation (no if/else) to make the following pairs of binary values (only 1 and 0) have the following results?

```
1 | 1 -> 0
0 | 1 -> 1
1 | 0 -> 1
0 | 0 -> 0
```

(The operation must be the same for every row).

Comment: XOR (`x^y` if you're using C/C++/Java). By the way, this has nothing to do with logarithm.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Bitwise_operation

Answer (score 0):

As hinted already by `barak manos`,

the **XOR(a^b)** operation on **two bits (a and b)** is defined as :-

```
a'b + b'a = a XOR b.     //   where a' represents negation(complement) of a
```

So, your queries are verified below :-

```
1'1 + 1'1 = 0 + 0 = 0
0'1 + 1'0 = 1 + 0 = 1
1'0 + 0'1 = 0 + 1 = 1
0'0 + 0'0 = 0 + 0 = 0.
```

This is the required result.

Comment: Kindly upvote and accept the answer if it helped! It's a bad habit of leaving answers unmarked and upvoted if they are true and they helped!

Comment: it's [complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement), not [compliment](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/compliment) which has a completely different meaning

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc- Oh,Yeah. Thanks a lot for pointing to such a silly mistake. .. Also, your profile picture is just awesome. :)